New UV Unwrapping Tools
I used to be able to copy and paste UV maps between faces in Blender. Now I have updated to Blender 4.3 and I can't find it anywhere. Nobody is talking about it. I do city renders and properly unwrapping building windows used to be a breeze. Now I am in the middle of a project and I can't continue unless I want to unwrap a million windows across a city scene individually. I have tried the Copy and Paste in the UV editor but it doesn't work. I need to be able to copy and paste UV maps within the same object as well as between objects. Also, I can't find this Object Menu I've seen mentioned. The Blender page seems to assume everyone knows where it is.

Has my new answer helped? If so, please, mark it with "accepted" tick.

It's in UV editor:

UV > Copy UVs

UV > Paste UVs



You can add these to quick favorites:

Right click while mouse hovers over specified menu item
'Add to Quick Favorites'
Call Quick favorites using Q button


Or you can assign shortcuts (for example,  Ctrl+C  /  Ctrl+V):

Right click while mouse hovers over specified menu item
'Assign Shortcut'
Ctrl+C  // or Ctrl+V


The user explained that it's not possible to do that in it's Blender version. Probably needs to explain a bit more

Nobody said that I does not work for any blender version. I'm saying that for this specific user it's not working, why? We don't know, the user needs to describe a bit more the steps followed. Probably a missing step or something

I need to be able to copy and paste UVs within the same object in Edit Mode.

@SeanCollett — I've updated my answer. Now it contains instruction how to copy UVs from one face to another within the same object.
